# PL SQL Trigger to update start time for row when a single column is updated

Tags: mysql, plsql, triggers

I'm fairly new to triggers and have already tried searching for a solution to my question with little results. I want to update a single row's start time column whenever it's active column is set to 1.

I have two columns `ACTIVE` (number) and  `START_TIME` (timestamp) in `my_table`. I would like to create a PL/SQL trigger that updates the `START_TIME` column to `current_timestamp` whenever an `update` statement has been applied to the `ACTIVE` column - setting it to 1.

So far I have only seen examples for inserting new rows or updating entire tables which isn't what I'm looking to do. I'd have thought there would be a fairly simple solution to my problem.

This is what I've got so far from other examples. I know the structure of my solution is poor and I'm asking for any input to modify my trigger to achieve my desired result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER routine_active
AFTER UPDATE ON my_table 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (my_table.ACTIVE = 1)
begin
    insert my_table.start_time = current_timestamp; 
end; 
\
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this .it may help you 
  write the update query instead of insert query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER routine_active
AFTER UPDATE ON my_table 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (new.ACTIVE = 1)
 begin
  update my_table  set start_time =current_timestamp;
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be a BEFORE UPDATE, not AFTER UPDATE, so it saves both changes with a single action.  Then you don't need the INSERT or UPDATE statements.  I also added the "OF active" clause, so it will only start this trigger if that column was updated, which may reduce the workload if other columns get updated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER routine_active
    BEFORE UPDATE OF active ON my_table
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF active = 1
    THEN
        :NEW.start_time = current_timestamp;
    END IF;
END;
```